# How can I get a single registration in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to do basic CRUD operations with LWC and Apex methods but when I do a SELECT, even if I add a WHERE or a LIMIT 1 to the query, it will only return a list, and I only want the data from the record.

This is my code:

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Contact> getSalesContact() {
    return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
    FROM Contact];
}
```

Js:

```
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import getSalesContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactCtrl.getSalesContact";

export default class CustomerInformationTab extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getSalesContact) cont;
}
```

HTML:

```
            <template if:true={cont.data}>
                <template for:each={cont.data} for:item="con">
                    <p key = {con.Id}>{con.FirstName}</p>
                </template>
            </template>  
            <template if:true={cont.error}>
                {cont.error}
            </template>
```

I know that I am returning a list, but if I do not put List<> then it does not work for me I tried to do the following, but it doesn't work for me:

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static Contact getSalesContact(String recordId) {
    return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id =: recordId];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the first value:

```
public static Contact getSalesContact() {
    return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
    FROM Contact][0];
}
```

You'll have to change your template, too, since the shape of the response will change.

---

```
<p key = {con.Id}>{con.FirstName}</p>
```

Would become:

```
<p>{cont.data.FirstName}</p>
```

Comment: How can I change the template,  I guess without the for?

Comment: @WillyKelly Correct. I edited that in.

Comment: It works, but this returns only the first of the list and I want it to return the one with the record, for example, if I could I would do this: 
    public static Contact getSalesContact(String recordId) {
        return [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone 
        FROM Contact WHERE Id =: recordId
    }
but don't let me

Comment: @WillyKelly Read about [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record). It does what you want without Apex, and also gives a demo.